# How do I select only those lists whose elements are all above a certain number?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I'm essentially doing coin flips, using `RandomReal` to populate a bunch of lists, each with 8 elements. I then want to select only those lists for which all elements are greater than a certain number, e.g. .5.

So far I have this:

```
class = RandomReal[1, {100, 8}];
pass = Select[class, #[[1]] > (.5) &]
```

but this doesn't work. I suspect a simple Select function would do the trick, but I can't seem to get the syntax right to test every element of the nested listed against a certain number and then only return those lists for which every element passes. Or indeed simply to return the number of sublists for which every element passes. Thanks.

Comment: `Select[class, And @@ Thread[# > .5] &]`

Comment: Conceptually, you want this: `Select[class, And @@ Map[# > 0.5 &, #] &]`. Performance-wise, you'd be better off with something like `Select[class, Total[UnitStep[0.5 - #]] == 0 &]`.

Comment: The Gods have answered so I might as well delete my answer, my answer was this: `Pick[class,Times @@ UnitStep[#] == 1 & /@ (class - 0.5)]`

Comment: @Pickett The intended effect of answering in comments isn't to preclude "real" answers, but to give some food for thought for the OP AND to other users that might want to elaborate a good post (in this case, for example  doing some perf. comps, etc). Ref: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1244/193

Comment: `Pick[#, Sign[(Min /@ #) - #2], 1] &[class, .5]` probably about as fast as possible, change second argument obviously for limit. Properly returns those sublists where all members are *greater* as your OP states.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm missing something but this seems like a straightforward application of [`Min`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Min.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
class = RandomReal[1, {100, 5}];

Select[class, Min[#] > 0.5 &]
```

> ```
> {{0.823403, 0.551229, 0.746259, 0.964339, 0.89009},
>  {0.745146, 0.714426, 0.809069, 0.833149, 0.725859}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This answer summarizes the answers given in the comments to this question. I have changed two parameter values to keep the output small. Since set the values of the two parameters with `With`, it will to restore the original values should that be desired.

```
With[{size = 4}, SeedRandom @ 42; class = RandomReal[1, {100, size}]];

With[{threshold = .6}, Column@Select[class, And @@ ((# > threshold &) /@ #) &]]

With[{threshold = .6}, Column@Select[class, And @@ Thread[# > threshold] &]]

With[{threshold = .6}, Column@Select[class, Total[UnitStep[threshold - #]] == 0 &]]

With[{threshold = .6}, Column@Pick[class, Times @@ UnitStep[#] == 1 & /@ (class - threshold)]]
```

All of the four above expressions return

> ```
> {0.717287,0.754353,0.860349,0.996966}
> {0.763037,0.631343,0.89637,0.621647}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it can be done also as follows:

```
Select[Select[#, # > 0.5 &] & /@ class, Length[#] == 8 &]
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
SeedRandom[3];
class = RandomReal[1, {100, 8}];
Select[AllTrue[# > 0.5 &]][class]
```

> {{0.681735, 0.630934, 0.746274, 0.772147, 0.919485, 0.768809,
> 0.950752, 0.909879}, {0.939844, 0.556898, 0.828244, 0.687478,
> 0.558535, 0.707213, 0.961479, 0.636546}}

Often returns an empty list for such a high threshold. I had to experiment with `SeedRandom` value, but not for long.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
class = RandomReal[1, {100, 8}];
Lookup[GroupBy[class, AllTrue[# > 0.5 &]], True, {}]

(*{{0.86521, 0.503485, 0.88936, 0.973814, 0.609053, 0.661455, 0.980263, 0.839613}, 
{0.982626, 0.848077, 0.595841, 0.685342, 0.771152, 0.801341, 0.638942, 0.537611}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. above**

```
SeedRandom[3];
class = RandomReal[1, {100, 8}];

above[n_][x_] /; Min[x] > n := x
above[_][_] := Nothing

above[0.5] /@ class
```

{{0.681735, 0.630934, 0.746274, 0.772147, 0.919485, 0.768809,
0.950752, 0.909879}, {0.939844, 0.556898, 0.828244, 0.687478,
0.558535, 0.707213, 0.961479, 0.636546}}

```
above[0.6] /@ class
```

{{0.681735, 0.630934, 0.746274, 0.772147, 0.919485, 0.768809,
0.950752, 0.909879}}

```
above[0.7] /@ class
```

{}

**2. Threshold**

We can also use `Threshold` which zeros out matrix elements with absolute value LESS than `n`:

```
Select[FreeQ @ 0.] @ Threshold[class, 0.5]
```

{{0.681735, 0.630934, 0.746274, 0.772147, 0.919485, 0.768809,
0.950752, 0.909879}, {0.939844, 0.556898, 0.828244, 0.687478,
0.558535, 0.707213, 0.961479, 0.636546}}

To include a value of exactly 0.5 we can subtract a small number from `n`:

```
m = {{0.681, 0.630, 0.746, 0.5}, {0.681, 0.630, 0.746, 0.51}};

Threshold[m, 0.5]
```

{{0.681, 0.63, 0.746, 0.}, {0.681, 0.63, 0.746, 0.51}}

```
Threshold[m, 0.5 - 10^-10]
```

{{0.681, 0.63, 0.746, 0.5}, {0.681, 0.63, 0.746, 0.51}}

Answer (score 0):

```mma
RandomReal[{1/2 + $MachineEpsilon,1|,{100,8}]
```

No testing needed.

Comment: Would there be any values below `0.5` ? I think the question is how to `select` such lists from randomly generated lists not how to `generate` a list with all values above a threshold.

Comment: On that point, I opine that the question was uclear. Generation and selection were both mentioned. I had the impression that the questioner may not have realized that *RandomReal* could be range restricted to the stated goal of having only lists with values  above 0.5. I concede that your interpretation is also reasonable.